# Button opens list of another buttons

Tags: list, button, hide, show

I want to make a button that when is clicked opens another sub-buttons under it. Like one main button which is shown and when clicked it opens sub-buttons, when clicked again it closes sub-buttons. [here is image explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6u8B.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const mainBtn = document.querySelector('#main')

mainBtn.addEventListener('click',() => {
  container.classList.toggle('active')
 })
```

```css
.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container button{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
 } 
#main{
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container.active button{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="main">Click me</button>
  <button class="inner">btn 1</button>
  <button class="inner">btn 2</button>
  <button class="inner">btn 3</button>
  <button class="inner">btn 4</button>

</div>
```